# Policy based Authorization not working in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get Policy based Authorization working in .net core 2.1 based on this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1

However I cannot seem to get it to fire.

In the below example, I've commented out the context.suceeed line, so I would have thought my api call to my usercontroller would fail.

However my API call is being accepted.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, VerifyAuthCookieHandler>();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("VerifyAuthCookie", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new VerifyAuthCookieRequirement()));
        });

        services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }

}
```

Here is my handler

```
public class VerifyAuthCookieHandler : AuthorizationHandler<VerifyAuthCookieRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   VerifyAuthCookieRequirement requirement)
    {

        //context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And here is my requirement:

```
public class VerifyAuthCookieRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{

    public VerifyAuthCookieRequirement()
    {

    }
}
```

And finally, my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Policy = "VerifyAuthCookie")]
public class UserController : Controller
{

}
```

If I add code in HandleRequirementAsync and set a breakpoint then it's not being hit when I debug, so my Handler doesn't appear to be called at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should call `app.UseAuthentication();` before the `app.UseMvc();` in the Configure method of the Startup class. This will add the ASP.NET Core authentication middleware to the request pipeline.

Since you are using `services.AddMvcCore()` we'll need to configure the authorization services manually, something `services.AddMvc()` does for you automatically. We should add `.AddAuthorization()` to the `IMvcCoreBuilder`.
This will add the default Authentication- and Authorization services and a PolicyEvaluator.

If you're interested in the exact services that will be registered in your DI container you should follow [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/747420e5aa7cc2c7834cfb9731510286ded6fc03/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs#L71) link.

Comment: Right, that was only a part of the issue, I was mistaken. Since you are using the .AddMvcCore() we'll need to configure Authorization a bit more in depth (something `.AddMvc()`) does for you. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: So, I *am* using `.AddMvc()` and have basically the same code as OP (names changed, but structure identical). I have the same issue. Is there more that could be the case?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, I fix it by :

> services.AddMvcCore().**AddAuthorization()**.AddJsonFormatters();